# Batch convert image files to webp and cleanup old files

Tags: shell, find

I am writing a shell script on Mac Terminal to convert a bunch of bitmap images (jpg/png) into webp format for website optimisation. I am using the cwebp converter. My script looks like this:

```
# Convert all the PNG and JPEG files to WebP format with 75 quality lossy compression
# Then delete all the unused JPEG/PNG files
find ./ -type f -name '*.png' -exec sh -c 'cwebp -q 75 $1 -o "${1%.png}.webp"' _ {} \;
find ./ -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'cwebp -q 75 $1 -o "${1%.jpg}.webp"' _ {} \;
find ./ -type f -name '*.jpeg' -exec sh -c 'cwebp -q 75 $1 -o "${1%.jpeg}.webp"' _ {} \;

find ./ -type f -name '.*jpg' -delete ;
find ./ -type f -name '.*jpeg' -delete ;
find ./ -type f -name '.*png' -delete ;
```

It is converting all the files but it is not cleaning up and removing all the old png and jpg versions of the files afterwards. No obvious errors are being thrown.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're using the UNIX version of `find`, which is completely unrelated to the Windows version of `find` (which is more like if you dropped `grep` on its head as a baby).

Comment: Oh I should mention I am using iTerm2 on Mac

Comment: Cool, you're just using the wrong tag then. You're writing a shell script, not a batch file. The [batch-file] tag is exclusively for the Windows command line. Almost nobody on this tag will be able to help you.

Comment: Your `find` commands that do the deletion have the wrong `-name`. You have the dot and asterisk swapped. The semi-colons are also unnecessary in the last 3 commands.

Comment: Thanks for the edits SomethingDark, that clears up a lot for me. @MarkSetchell works so good now! Thanks for picking up the syntax errors!

Comment: You should be able to avoid 2 passes and also only remove files if the conversion succeeds by changing to `'cwebp -q 75 $1 -o "${1%.png}.webp"' && rm "$1"`